# AJAX call not hitting WebAPI method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am using one WebAPI method which needs to be called through jQuery AJAX. Below is the jQuery code used for the AJAX call:

```js
var BlogAndStoryComment = new Object();
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentID = 0;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentUserName = userName;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentText = commentText;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentApprovedByUserID = 0;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentDate = "date";
BlogAndStoryComment.HtmlComment = commentHtml;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentIsSpam = 0;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentIsApproved = 0;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentEmail = email;
BlogAndStoryComment.CommentCount = 0;
BlogAndStoryComment.OnCommentID = 0;
BlogAndStoryComment.BlogID = blogID;
BlogAndStoryComment.SiteID = siteID;
BlogAndStoryComment.RowCount = 0;

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:55052/API/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(BlogAndStoryComment),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {},
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
  failure: function(response) {}
});
```

This is my WebAPI method:

```
[Route("api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments")]
[VersionedRoute("", 1)]
[ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetAndPostBlogComments([FromBody] BlogAndStoryComment comment)
{
}
```

When I call this method from the AJAX call it is hitting the `error` function which gives me a `statustext` or `"error"`. However when I call through Postman then method is working correctly. What is the issue?

Comment: If you check the response text of the request in the console what is the exact error provided?

Comment: HI Rory I am getting this error in console "response for preflight has invalid http status code 405"

Comment: That error means that the request is being interpreted as being cross domain. Is the JS code running on the same `http://localhost:55052` URL? If not, that's your issue. You need to amend the API so that it adds CORS headers to the response.

Comment: JS code is running from different url and http://localhost:55052 url having web api method that needs to hit. i added in web api project web.config access control headers already. and the same done in the JS code solution web.config also. but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

For simple type,  on server side:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string name)
{
}
```

on the client side, you just define if you want to send in json format:

```
    var dataJSON = "test";

    $('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
    function GeneralPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            //url: '../api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            //url: '~/api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

If you want to make it work in complex type, from server side you should define:

```
public class RecipeInformation
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(RecipeInformation information)
    {
    }
}
```

And from client side:

```
    var dataJSON = { name: "test" };

    $('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
    function GeneralPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            //url: '../api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            //url: '~/api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this and use the jquery param method

```
    var postData = {
        name : 'name'
    }

    $('#testPostMethod').bind("click", GeneralPost);
    function GeneralPost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            //url: '~/api/comments/GetAndPostBlogComments',
            data: $.param(postData,true),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```